# Why do constructors in java not have a return type?

Tags: java, constructor, return-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why constructor not returns value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-constructor-not-returns-value)

Why don't constructors have a return type, not even void? What's the reason for that?

Comment: @tylerl: Not an exact duplicate, since that question doesn't name a language and its answers refer to a mix of different languages, while this question is specifically about Java.

Comment: Why don't C++ constructors have return types?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the [suggested question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-constructor-not-returns-value). This question relates specifically to Java, as @DanielPryden comments, whereas the "duplicate" is language-neutral.

Comment: @biziclop you would store it in a variable, thus cancelling the need for a return type since a constructor already creates a new object, nice retoric there :) However, some other languages require a constructor to specifically declare 'void' as return type. On one hand, this makes it explicitly clear, on the other not declaring a return type makes the constructor signature more easily recognizable.

Comment: @biziclop I would like return `null`. That way when I build a `newObject = new Object(varName)` in which `varName = null` I can get a `newObject = null`. Makes sense?

Comment: @Cawas That sounds like a not so good idea. If you could do that, you'd have no way of knowing whether a variable was null without checking it. If you want to signal that the object couldn't be created, you can throw an exception.

Comment: But what's the problem with checking it? To throw the exception at some point, something had to be checked at another point. I ask all this without knowing any better. ;)

Answer (score 52):

Constructor is internally a **nonstatic method with name `<init>` and `void` return type**. It does not return anything. Internally first object is allocated and then its constructor is called. Object is not allocated with constructor itself.
In other words the syntax `new Object()` not only calls the constructor but also creates new object and after calling the constructor returns it. The [Suns' Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) stands that "The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object." Initialize does not mean create.

Answering the question. Missing return type declaration is a way in which you distinguish the constructor from a method. But you can return from constructor as from void method. For example this code compiles and runs correctly:

```
public class TheClass {
    public TheClass(){
        return;
    }
    public void TheClass(){ //confusing, but this is void method not constructor
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[]a){
        TheClass n = new TheClass();
        n.TheClass();//void method invocation
    }
}
```

This class has one void method (*don't try it at home* - uppercase method is a bad style) and one constructor. The difference is in declared return type.

Look at this JNI code snippet which demonstrates that constructor is a nonstatic void method:

```
 jstring
 MyNewString(JNIEnv *env, jchar *chars, jint len)
 {
     jclass stringClass;
     jmethodID cid;
     jcharArray elemArr;
     jstring result;

     stringClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
     if (stringClass == NULL) {
         return NULL; /* exception thrown */
     }
 /* Get the method ID for the String(char[]) constructor */
     cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, stringClass,
                               "<init>", "([C)V");
     if (cid == NULL) {
         return NULL; /* exception thrown */
     }

     /* Create a char[] that holds the string characters */
     elemArr = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, len);
     if (elemArr == NULL) {
         return NULL; /* exception thrown */
     }
     (*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, elemArr, 0, len, chars);

     result = (*env)->AllocObject(env, stringClass);
     if (result) {
         (*env)->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(env, result, stringClass,
                                          cid, elemArr);
         /* we need to check for possible exceptions */
         if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
             (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, result);
             result = NULL;
         }
     }
     /* Free local references */
     (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, elemArr);
     (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, stringClass);
     return result;
 }
```

especially these fragments:

```
 /* Get the method ID for the String(char[]) constructor */
 cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, stringClass, "<init>", "([C)V");
```

and then

```
 /* Allocate new object. */
 result = (*env)->AllocObject(env, stringClass);
 if (result) {
      /* Call uninitialized objects' constuctor. */
      (*env)->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(env, result, stringClass, cid, elemArr);
```

first object is allocated and then nonstatic `<init>` method is called. For details look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626131057/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/fldmeth.html#26254). The [AllocObject function documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20111103051656/http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16337) stands that "Allocates a new Java object without invoking any of the constructors for the object. Returns a reference to the object." So in JVM object is not allocated by constructor, but only initialized by it. Looking in constructors' bytecode we are seeing that no object is returned (exactly like in void methods).

Another way, when you dissasemble sample class, you will see invocation of parent (Object) constructor from its constructor:

```
#javap -c NewClass
Compiled from "NewClass.java"
public class NewClass extends java.lang.Object{
public NewClass();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

}
```

Note that the `<init>` method is not actually part of the Java language. Rather, it is something the Java virtual machine expects to see in a Java class file. This distinction is significant because the Java language does not depend on the class file. Java source can be compiled into other binary formats, including native executables. A Java compiler that translates Java language source into some other binary format need not generate a method named `<init>`, so long as objects are initialized in the proper way at the proper time. The Java Language Specification (JLS) details the order of initialization and when it occurs, but doesn't say how it is actually accomplished.

But I see that we're talking about JVM here.

For some of nonbelievers this is example (thx biziclop) which shows that object exists and is allocated before returning from constructor:

```
   class AnotherClass {

        private String field;
        public static AnotherClass ref;

        public AnotherClass() {
            this.field = "value";
            AnotherClass.ref = this;
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return field;
        }
    }

    public class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] a) {
            try {
                new AnotherClass();
                return;
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                System.out.println("exception");
            }
            System.out.println("instance: " + AnotherClass.ref);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your wisdom. I am assuming first code snippet is from JVM? Can you give some link to that code?

Comment: This is link from JNI specification. Link is in answer, but I can put it here too http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/fldmeth.html#26254

Comment: It's not clear to me that JNI initialization accurately represents the inner workings of the VM. Please explain.

Comment: @Ben: if you are not convinced read  [AllocObject function description](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16337). It stands that it "Allocates a new Java object without invoking any of the constructors for the object. Returns a reference to the object." How can it be possible if the constructor allocates the object?

Comment: @Ben: another thing is that when you look in constructors' bytecode you will see that no object is returned (exactly like in void methods).

Comment: @zacheusz AllocObject returns a jobject. A jobject is not the same thing as an object. According to this, a jobject is stored outside the heap to help with native code object visibility. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2009-April/001518.html I think of JNI as a way to manipulate the VM by pulling various control strings like on a mannequin which is not a way to access the inner workings of the JVM.

Comment: @Ben: AFAIK, the jobject is a reference to new, allocated but uninitialized object on the heap. The jobject variable is not on the heap as this mail stands. If you not trust JNI, look at bytecode. The return statements are easily readable there :]

Comment: Another proof that the object gets fully created before the constructor is invoked is to throw an exception from the constructor. If you made the mistake of publishing `this` to another object, the reference will stay alive and be fully usable. And yet another one is deserialisation, where no constructor is invoked at all.

Comment: @biziclop: good point, I've added your example

Comment: "downvoters (2 for now) please explain yourself". I always downvote people that put this in their answer. Seriously, if someone doesn't agree with something, they may or may not leave a comment about it, you are not that important to make them return to your answer just to justify themselves.

Comment: @M28: IMHO you don't understand how it works here. **We are voting on post not peoples.** You said that "I always downvote people". This is not presidental election. It's not about answer author but other readers. From my point of view the votes and answer are for them and for OP, not for the answer author.

Comment: @M28 I think you misunderstood the rules. Please take the time to read the manual on what [vote down](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) means. Note how not agreeing is missing from the criteria listed.

Answer (score 3):

How would you get the returned value? What kind of value are you interested in, being returned? How would you declare the return type?

```
 X x = new X ();
```

assigns an X-reference to x. Now, if `new X` would return something, how should you get it?

```
 class X { 
     public int X () { 
          return 42;
     }
 }
```

What's the logic of returning something from the ctor? An error message? Some loginfo? Write it to a file, or to an attribute, which you poll later.

Since the ctor is only accessed once per object, the only reason I can think of, to use another return value, would be, to inform about the process of creation itself.

```
 class X { 
     private Y y;
     public int X () { 
          y = new Y ();
     }
     public Y getY () { return y; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the VM implementation of a constructor isn't to return any value, in practice it kind of does - the new object's reference. It would then be syntactically weird and / or confusing to be able to store one or both of the new object's reference and an additional return value in one statement.

Comment: it is about syntax. For example the `i++` operator has more logic as it looks like. Sun Java tutorial stands that _The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object._ - it explains everything :)