# Why is there a return inside a Java Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I was looking at some framework and noticed there is a return in the constructor of one of the classes. I don't get it. What is it for?

It looks like this:

```
public class Hello {

    HashMap<String, String> myMap;
    Stack<HashMap<Sting, String>> myStack;

    public Hello() {        
        myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myStack = new Stack<HashMap<String, String>>();
        return;  
    }

    ... more methods
}
```

Comment: Other answers are valid, though it really doesn't make much sense to have `return` as the last statement of a method.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I got confused and was wondering if I was missing some technical knowledge..

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. Seems like a coding standard thing -- all methods must have exactly one return. Of course, I could be wrong

Answer (score 3):

Straight From [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

> Any method declared void doesn't return a value. It does not need to
>   contain a return statement, but it may do so. In such a case, a return
>   statement can be used to branch out of a control flow block and exit
>   the method and is simply used like this:
>
> return;

The same applies for **return; syntax** declared in the constructor.

Comment: yeah, I understand the purpose of using "return;" to exit a control flow, and may have used it before. However, this "return;" is in the constructor. Why is that even necessary? What is it doing? Btw, thank you very much for helping!

Comment: @user1739658 tbh, in your case it is just redundant.

Comment: @user1739658 also check this awesome link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801500/why-do-constructors-in-java-not-have-a-return-type

Comment: Thank you again! I guess maybe the return used to be useful/not-redundant before but someone changed the code and didn't remove it. I am not familiar with the use of the Stack class in Java and wanted to make sure that return is not in some way related to the stack member variable, and also to make sure that it's not because I haven't had enough development experience to tell the use of it.

Comment: @you are welcome :) please dont forget to accept an answer which was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

It does nothing.

You can have `return` statements in your constructors as a way of flow control

```
public MyClass(boolean male, int children) {
  this.male = male;
  if (this.male) {
    return;
  }
  this.children = children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return just means to exit the method. Without a value, it returns nothing. Since it is at the end of the method, it is redundant, since the method will exit anyways.