# Polymorphism: Constructor won't accept arguments

Tags: java, constructor, arguments, polymorphism

When I compile this, I get an error message saying expected constructor arguments for Video are "no arguments"

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Thing
{

}

class Video extends Thing
{
    String description;
    int price;
    String title;

    void Video ( String d , int p, String t)
    {
        this.description = d;
        this.price = p;
        this.title = t;
    }

    String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}

class BookOnTape extends Thing
{
    String description;

    void BookOnTape ( String d )
    {
        description = d;
    }

    String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}

class Funiture extends Thing
{
   String description;

    void Furniture ( String d )
    {
        description = d;
    }

    String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}

public class Lookup
{
    /*private static HashMap<Thing, Integer> rentalList;

    static
    {
        rentalList = new HashMap<Thing, Integer>();
        rentalList.put( new Video(5), new Integer( 0 ) );
    }*/

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        System.out.println("fart");

        Thing farmer = new Video( "fgfg", 5, "gfgf" );
    }
}
```

When I compile this:

```
class A
{
}

class B extends A
{
    String name;

    B ( String n )
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
}


class TestPoly
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        A poly = new B( "test" );
    }
}
```

It works fine. I don't see the difference. Is there something wrong here?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void Video ( String d , int p, String t)
```

This is not a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). That's why the compiler complains: it cannot find the constructor `Video(String, int, String)` because it is not there in the code. Delete the `void` would turn it into one, since a method needs a return value, while a constructor does not have one.

A (much) more informative discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801500/why-do-constructors-in-java-not-have-a-return-type).

Answer (score 0):

```
void Video ( String d , int p, String t) is a method not a constructor.
```

> `Constructor's` don't have return type not even void.

now, this is a constructor:

```
 Video ( String d , int p, String t)
```