# Where is the bug from the default constructor question?

Tags: java, debugging, constructor

I'm a java self-learner and got stumped with one question about constructor. I got some hints that there's a problem in `public void Circle()`, but I still don't know how to debug this.. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance :)

```
public class Circle {
    public Color color;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.color.setDescription("Red");
        System.out.println(circle.color.getDescription());
    } 

    public void Circle() {
        Color color = new Color();
    }

    public class Color {
        String description;

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably that it's creating a local variable that is shadowing the `color` variable. Also it has `void` in the method signature, so it isnt a constructor

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801500/why-do-constructors-in-java-not-have-a-return-type

Answer (score 3):

That **is not** a constructor. A constructor is not a `void` method. Also, you have a local `color` variable in your method. I think you wanted

```
public Circle() {
    this.color = new Color();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A constructor in Java is a special method that is used to initialize objects. The constructor is called when an object of a class is created.

In your case, you are calling `public void Circle()`

**Note** that the constructor name must match the class name, and it cannot have a return type (like **void**).

*Also note that the constructor is called when the object is created.*

All classes have constructors by default: if you do not create a class constructor yourself, *Java creates one for you*. However, then you are not able to set initial values for object attributes.

So in your case the constructor should be similar to :

```
public Circle() {
    //what ever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Circle() {
    this.color = new Color();
}
```

constructor don’t have a return type