# Adding string items to a list of type Person in C#

Tags: c#, object

I'm making a simple registration application and I have an assignment to learn more about lists. I have an assignment that says that i am to create a class called Persons and in that class set the values from the text fields in variables and add this to a list of type Person.

So far:

In the `Person` class:

```
string strSocialSecurityNumber = string.Empty;//---( This will not be used now.)
string strFirstName = string.Empty;
string strLastName = string.Empty;
string strFullName = string.Empty;
string strAge = string.Empty;
string strAll = string.Empty;
int intAge = 0;
List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>();

public void SetValues(string FirstName, string LastName, int Age)
{
    strFirstName = FirstName;
    strLastName = LastName;
    strFullName = strFirstName + " " + strLastName;
    intAge = Age;
    strAge = Convert.ToString(intAge);
    strAll = strAge + " " + strFullName;

}

public List<Person> Person()
{
    lstPerson.Add(strAll);
    return lstPerson;
}
```

Error message: 
"can not convert from string to Person"

The assignment says that the list is to be of the type Person so I am supposed to add strings to it. I've looked how to do this but I don't know how. I have seen that there are options like "ConvertAll" But I'm not sure if I am allowed to use it since the list should be of type Person.

Comment: You have list of persons, so you have to insert Persons. If you are getting input as a string, you might want to consider that to a person and then add to the list.

Comment: ^ this. The assignment asks you to use values from text fields to set values  in a Person instance, then add the Person instance to the list.

Comment: At first i think that you should read about constructors. You are trying to execute constructor that returns value of type specified by you, what is wrong. Here you can read a bit why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-a-constructor-does-not-return-a-value

Comment: The class Person should not contain the list that keeps track of all persons. What you want to do in OOP is to abstract object-related properties in a class (eg. for a person that's age, name, ...). The list of all persons should not be a property of a single person object.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast replies, I belive I have gotten my answer here. 

 IDontKnowPopePersonally: I tried making the SetValues as a constructor but then the soloution i got from "irsog" did not work since it requierd arguments. 

I think i do understand what you mean, better to use a constructor to assign values to variables then creating a method.

thanks for the help guys, I hope to return the favor soon

Comment: @zimdanen Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both having a list of Person and all the properties in the Person class i a little confusing.
I think the teacher meant that you should create a Persons class containing a list of Person.

```
public class Person
{
    public string strFirstName;
    ...
}

public class Persons
{
    List<Person> lstPersons = new List<Person>();

    public void AddPerson(string FirstName, ...)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.strFirstName = FirstName;
        ...
        lstPersons.Add(person);
    }
}
```

I believe that this is more like what the assignment is requesting.

Comment: Well this does seem alot more reasonable then what I did, thank you!

Ive never asked questions here before, normaly im used to finding answers here so I don´t really know how to mark the soloutions i get as answers to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert string to person 
you must use this

```
 public List<Person> Person()
    {
        lstPerson.Add(new Person(){strAge =yourvalue,...});
        return lstPerson;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked!

So basically i needed to create a new instance of the list(new person)

Why is this needed? And do i need to do this every time i add something to the list?

thanks!

Comment: because you make a list of person and you can not convert string type to person,you must add a type of person to list.mark my solution as answer if it helped you:)