# Return false from __constructor

Tags: php

Can you return false from the contructor?

```
<?php


class ftp_stfp{

    //private vars of the class
    private $host;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $connection_type;
    private $connection = false;


    function __contruct( $host, $username, $password, $connection_type ){

        //setting the classes vars
        $this->host         = $host;
        $this->username     = $username;
        $this->password     = $password;
        $this->connection_type = $connection_type;

        //now set the connection into this classes connection
        $this->connection = $this->connect();

        //check the connection was set else return false
        if($this->connection === false){
            return false;   
        } 
    } ... etc etc the rest of the class
```

Call the class:

```
$ftp_sftp = new ftp_sftp( $host, $uname, $pword, $connection_type );
```

Is this actually correct, ie would the $ftp_sftp var either be false or hold the class depending on outcome of the __construct method, or is this completely wrong logic?

Comment: Why not throw an Exception?

Comment: Technically you can return other Objects from constructor, but this is bad practice. Here is an example: https://es6console.com/jseq9j8l/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Constructors do not have return values. If you require getting some kind of result from a constructor you can do a few things:

If you need a return value either use a method to do the heavy lifting (usually called `init()`).

```
public static function init( $host, $username, $password, $connection_type ){

    //setting the classes vars
    $this->host         = $host;
    $this->username     = $username;
    $this->password     = $password;
    $this->connection_type = $connection_type;

    //now set the connection into this classes connection
    $this->connection = $this->connect();

    //check the connection was set else return false
    if($this->connection === false){
        return false;   
    } 
}

$ftp_sftp = ftp_sftp::init();
```

Store the results in a member variable and check its value after calling the constructor.

```
function __construct( $host, $username, $password, $connection_type ){

    //setting the classes vars
    $this->host         = $host;
    $this->username     = $username;
    $this->password     = $password;
    $this->connection_type = $connection_type;

    //now set the connection into this classes connection
    $this->connection = $this->connect();
}

$ftp_sftp = new ftp_sftp( $host, $uname, $pword, $connection_type );
if ($ftp_sftp->connection !== false)
{
    // do something
}
```

You can have your `connect()` method throw an exception. That will stop execution immediately and go to your `catch` block:

```
private method contect()
{
    // connection failed
    throw new Exception('connection failed!');
}

try 
{
    $ftp_sftp = new ftp_sftp( $host, $uname, $pword, $connection_type );
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: yea i thought that would be the case, thank you for the rapid answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Constructors can't return values. You can throw an exception in this stuation:

```
if($this->connection === false){
  throw new Exception('Connection can not be established.');  
}
```

Then you can instantiate variable in a try-catch block.

```
try
{
  $ftp_sftp = new ftp_sftp( $host, $uname, $pword, $connection_type );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  //Do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting thread on why the constructors have no return values [Why do constructors not return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-a-constructor-does-not-return-a-value).

Further it seems that by returning "False" you want to negate the object instantiation. If this is the case I would suggest that you thrown an exception if the connection fails and this way the object creation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an object outside and directly use your connect() method and test there

```
$ftp_sftp = new ftp_sftp( $host, $uname, $pword, $connection_type );
$ftp_sftp->connect();
```

if connect is public.