# Return a subclass in constructor Method

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, design-patterns, constructor

I have a base class which when I call constructor which accesses the system and depending on the configuration and return me  a subclass of it.
The main idea and the class was abstract his own factory, and returns to a sub-class as needed, depending on the config system.

I represented my idea into a draft in C + +, not necessarily to be something specific to him, but for a general approach for other language like java, etc..

is possible?

Example:

```
class system {
    public:
        Config config;
}

class Base {
    public:
        Base() {
            if(System.getInstance().config == Config.FooMode) {
                Foo foo = new Foo();
                return foo;
            }
        };
};

class Foo: public Base {
    public:
        float a;
        float b;
        float c;
}

class Boo: public Base {
    public:
        float d;
        float f;
        float g;
}

int main() {
    Point point = new Point();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a [factory method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-pattern-in-c-correctly) instead.

Comment: Constructors do not return in either C++ or Java (or C# for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible. Constructors don't return anything, use another method as a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) method.

```
class Base
{
  Foo makeFoo()
  {
  }
  ...
};
```

*I confused your code is C++ or Java, so don't know what code I should use.*

Answer (score 0):

You might need to brush up your basic OO concepts. `Constructors` don't return anything. Well, in some sense they do return the `instance` of the `class` but you can't use any of the `return` types with `constructors`. Not even `void`. Why ? read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values)

Comment: That's not universally true. In Objective-C, constructors return and they can return instances of subclasses. In JavaScript, which originally uses prototype-based OO, constructors (functions) return as well.