# Java Defining Methods In Objects

Tags: java, object

```
class Person {
private String name;
private int age;

Person() {
    this.name = "";
    this.age = 0;
}

Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

void getName(String name) {

}
}
```

I am new to Java and was practicing making objects. In the code above I created a Person object with two overloaded constructors. I hope those are correct. I tried making a method without specifying that returns void and got an error. Do methods inside of objects always require a return type? I'm not sure why the IDE gave me an error when I didn't specify it as void.

*edit I realized I never actually created the Person object, only the Person class.

Comment: What error? You just haven't specified any access modifier, so you have to be careful where you are trying to call the constructor or method.

Comment: There is no error in your code. And what you have defined are constructors and not normal methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That is not an issue

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ On its own, it isn't. But trying to call the `getName` method from a class in another package is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods require a return type, or `void`, as part of their signature.  `void` indicates that you are not returning anything, or if the `return` keyword is used, it is not followed by any value.

Constructors are special - they are not defined with a return type, as they always return the object they are instantiating and they are always named the same as the class name.

Comment: So what I have done for my getName() method was correct? I just have to specify the return type of each method inside an object.

Comment: I see nothing syntatically wrong with your method.  Sure, there's no method *body*, but that's still syntatically correct...If this were a conventional getter, however, its return type would be the same as the field you're returning (in this case, `String`), and it would accept no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private int age;

public Person() 
{
this.name = "";
this.age = 0;
}

public Person(String name, int age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}

public static Person GetObect() 
{
    return new Person("Steven N",22);


}
public void ShowDetails()
{
System.Out.Println("Name "+this.name+" and age is "+this.age);

}

}
class TestObject
{
public static void main(string arg[])
{
Person ob=Person.GetObject();
ob.ShowDetails();
}

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you are Welcome Steven N .

Comment: @StevenN Please free to ask any queries as you are a beginner?

Comment: ok StevenN doesn't matter carry your work hard if any problem occurs in java, C#, VB.NET , SQl , MySQL , SQL Server 2008 feel free you can contact me on this email address essa_rind2002@yahoo.com or you can add me on facebook https://www.facebook.com/GeoRind

Answer (score 0):

where is the person object you created,there are only 2 constructor, one method and a class `Person`.Object are created like this way `Person p =new Person();`
All methods must have a return type like `void` or `int` or `String` or anything that extends `Object` class but [constructor do not have  any return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values)
As you are new to java see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95419/what-are-all-the-different-ways-to-create-an-object-in-java) to know the different ways of creating objects

Comment: constructor don't have any return type ... If you specify return type in constructor you will get compilation error.