# Assigning a return value from a constructor

Tags: c#

I have the following class but I can't seem to get the desired results with C#.

```
public class AppOsType  {
    public static class IOS {
        public static int IOS()
        {
            return 100;
        }
        public static string ToString() 
        {
            return "iOS";
        }
    }
    ... // additional values
}
```

I want to get the following results:

```
AppOsType.IOS // returns 100
AppOsType.IOS.ToString() // returns "iOS"
```

But I'm getting an error saying `AppOsType.IOS` is a type when i do the following:

```
Assert.AreEqual(100, AppOsType.IOS);
```

What am I missing?

Edit: left out `static`.

Comment: You are better off using an Enum in this case. or a colleciton of static strings

Comment: how does it compile ? `IOS` method should be static

Comment: No, a method cannot have the same name of the class, and a constructor cannot return anything

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why all the static and inner class stuff is needed for, why don't you keep it simple and define an enum:

```
 public enum AppOsType
 {
      IOS = 100
 }
```

Then use

```
var ios = AppOsType.IOS;
var number = (int)ios;
var name = ios.ToString();
```

If you need to return a translated string based on enum, you could add a dictionary:

```
 var translations = new Dictionary<AppOsType, string>()
 {
     { AppOsType.IOS, "iOs" }
 }
```

and then

```
var ios = AppOsType.IOS;
var number = (int)ios;
var name = translations[ios];
```

Comment: Can't change existing implementation, otherwise I'll trigger a major refactor. :( All I can do is just change the  `AppOsType` like classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this nested static class inside the AppOsType class then you need to change something because a method cannot have the same name of the class and a [constructor cannot return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values). (Think to the fact as if the return value of the constructor is already defined to be the instance of the class)

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(AppOsType.IOS.Version);
    Console.WriteLine(AppOsType.IOS.ToString());
}

public class AppOsType  
{
    // .... other members here ?? ...
    public static class IOS 
    {
        public static readonly int Version;
        static IOS()
        {
            // In the static constructor you could set the readonly
            // static property
            Version = 100;
        }
        public static string ToString() 
        {
            return "iOS";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not necessary to have the static class, feel free to reconstruct the class, but still achieving the same result with the two expected results

Comment: Then, if you have only these two properties, why not make them part of the outer class? I can't see any logical reason to not do that

Answer (score 0):

Its becaus IOS is a class. `AppsOsType.IOS` points to the static class. If your Method `public int IOS()` would be static, you can access it using `AppOsType.IOS.IOS()`

Comment: Yes that I understand, but that's not the desired syntax I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an enum for some reason, to make it work with desired syntax, you need a public property (not a ctor or method) :

```
public class AppOsType  {
    public static class IOS {
        public static  int IOS
        {
            get { return 100; }
        }
        public static string ToString() 
        {
            return "iOS";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting this error with my existing and your code as well - `'IOS': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`

Comment: Because both the code has constructor with return types :) This is not a valid code. You cannot have constructor with return types

Comment: @CincauHangus, you are right, can you change the type name or the property name ?

Comment: @Guillaume unfortunately I can't, existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name `IOS` so change this

```
AppOsType.IOS // returns 100 [error]
```

> to

```
AppOsType.IOS.IOS // might returns 100
```