# java Creating an instance of a class from the constructor of another class

Tags: java

I have two classes, Game and ScoreBoard. I want an instance of ScoreBoard to be generated automatically when I create an instance of Game.

The ScoreBoard constructor looks like this:

```
public void ScoreBoard(String player1, String player2)
{
    p1Name = player1;
    p2Name = player2;
    p1Score = 0;
    p2Score = 0;
}
```

and the constructor of the Game class looks like this:

```
public Game()
{ 
  //irrelevant code redacted 
  ScoreBoard scores = new ScoreBoard(p1, p2);
}
```

when I try to compile, I get the following message:

> cannot find symbol - constructor ScoreBoard(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5):

A constructor doesn't have a return type. Remove the `void`.

```
public /* void */ ScoreBoard(String player1, String player2)
```

Comment: give u +1 for explaining why?

Comment: @KickButtowski that was already asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values)

Comment: [JLS-8.8. Constructor Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) which says (in part) *The `SimpleTypeName` in the `ConstructorDeclarator` must be the simple name of the class that contains the constructor declaration; otherwise a compile-time error occurs. In all other respects, the constructor declaration looks just like a method declaration that has no result ([§8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)).*