# C++ Constructor Implicit Return Type

Tags: c++, constructor

I am having some trouble understanding the return type for constructors, my professor stated ​that

"A constructor doesn't return anything from a code standpoint. Meaning, when you declare it, you don't declare a return value.

It implicitly returns a pointer (meaning, you can't change the behavior), however. As a side note, it returns the 'this' pointer. All of this is out of the hands of the programmer though."

Is this saying when you create an object the constructor passes a pointer, or am I completely off here?

Comment: Your professor is incorrect, a constructor has an implicit parameter `this` that is passed in, but from a compiler perspective the return would be `void`

Comment: The constructor is always expected to produce a usable value of the class type. So it doesn't `return` anything because the "result" of calling it is always the newly constructed object (not a pointer! -- that is entirely wrong). Since this is mandated by the spec it is indeed out of the hands of the programmer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it makes no sense. I suspect he's talking about `new foo;`, but not all constructor calls involve `new`.

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values

Answer (score 3):

If we called it an "initializer" rather than a "constructor" would that make it more understandable?

A constructor does not actually create an object. It initializes the object.

There is nothing to return. The object is created using new or auto or static allocation.

Comment: Besides *initialization* it has the effect of *transforming memory into an object*, this may seem like a philosophical thing, it does matter as the language has behavior associated to the moment objects become into existence or die away.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors do not have return types because they're not functions.  It's like asking what is the return type of `int i;`  It doesn't make sense, `int i` is not an expression, and neither is `Foo f;`.

It might help to see what the C equivalency to a constructor is.

Consider the following C++ code...

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int i) : m_i(i)
    {
    }

  private:
    int m_i;
};

int main (void)
{
  Foo f(5);

  return 0;
}
```

In C, we would have implemented the same as...

```
typedef struct Foo {
  int m_i;
} Foo_t;

Foo_init (Foo_t * self, int i)
{
  self->m_i = i;
}

int main (void)
{
  Foo_t f; // This is the "Constructor" in C
  Foo_init(&f, 5); // Which is decorated with this logic.

  return 0;
}
```

[Why do constructors not return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values) (thanks @tivn) is recommended reading for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two prospective for looking at a constructor, often discussions about them confuse the two causing it to be difficult to reference. (Note that I am going to gloss over definition vs declaration below and treat them as one thing to simplify the comparison)

The prospective you are talking about is the definition of a constructor. The definition of a constructor does not have a return type because you do not need to return anything. The closest thing you could have to a return type is void from a definition stand point.

There are two reasons that constructors do not have a return type of void. The first it is allows a method with the same name as the class to be defined, since the call site is unambiguous, and the lack of return type makes the definition unambiguous. The second is to avoid confusion at the call site as to the return type, `new Foo()` "returns" a `Foo*` which isn't `void`.

As others have said think of the constructor not as creating the actual object (which is handled elsewhere) but instead creating (or initializing) the properties of the object (setting up invariants and handling defaults).