# error: constructor Droid in class Droid cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, constructor, program-entry-point, default-constructor

I'm going through java on Codecademy, and in a very simple file, I get this error message that has something to do with constructor parameter.

I searched other similar questions/answers but they were about missing parameter, which I don't think is the case here.

```
public class Droid {

//parameters
  int batteryLevel=100;
  String name;

//constructor
  public void Droid(String droidName){
name=droidName;  }  

//main

  public static void main(String []args){

    Droid robot1 = new Droid("Jack");
    System.out.println(robot1);


  }
```

error: constructor Droid in class Droid cannot be applied to given types;
    Droid robot1 = new Droid("Jack");
                   ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove return type from constructor:

```
public Droid(String droidName){
    name=droidName;  }
```

See [Why do constructors not return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values)

> the reason the constructor doesn't return a value is because it's not called directly by your code, it's called by the memory allocation and object initialization code in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

delete "void" from constructor

Comment: Welcome to SO, you have to explain more for others to solve your issue, Plus if you put your sample code and specify what wen wrong it will help you to get a better answers from others and helps other to have a clear view about the question. Also there is no Tag added to the question.