# error: constructor student in class student cannot be applied to given types; super(name,enroll);

Tags: javascript, java, inheritance, constructor

I have declared the super right in the beginning. but it still shows the error that it is not. Also the constructor in parent class has the same parameter as those written in "super()". still it says that parameters don't match

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
     class student
    {
      public String name;
      public int enroll;
    
      public void student(String name, int enroll)
      {
        this.name=name;
        this.enroll=enroll;
      }
    }
    class Science extends student
    {
      int phy;
      int chem;
      int maths;
      public void Science(String name, int enroll, int phy, int chem, int maths)
      {
        super(name,enroll);
        this.phy=phy;
        this.chem=chem;
        this.maths=maths;
      }
    }
    class Arts extends student
    {
      int eng;
      int hist;
      int eco;
      public void Arts(String name, int enroll, int eng, int hist, int eco)
      {
        super(name,enroll);
        this.eng=eng;
        this.hist=hist;
        this.eco=eco;
      }
      
    }
    public class asd
    {
      //enter code here
      public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
      {
        //enter code here
       } 
      
    }
```

Comment: `public void student` <- this is not a constructor definition. Constructors do not have a return type (no, not even void). You instead created a method called `student`. Get rid of the `void` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, you need to remove `void` from [Constructors](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-constructor) since they don't have any explicit return type. You can check this answer to find out [why constructors not return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values).

So your current constructors which look like this:

```java
public void student(String name, int enroll)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.enroll=enroll;
}
```

should look like this instead, also the class name should start with uppercase letter as per [standard java conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions):

```
class Student {

  public Student(String name, int enroll)
  {
    this.name=name;
    this.enroll=enroll;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @OH GOD SPIDERS, void return type is making it method instead of constructor and compiler is checking super(name, enroll) against default constructor super(), removing return type should resolve it