# Why a Constructor in Java doesn’t have a return type?

Tags: java, constructor

I've read that constructors are automatically invoked when an object is created, but I'd like a more in-depth explanation regarding why they are different from regular methods in this aspect. Any examples or additional details to illustrate the reasoning behind this would be greatly appreciated.

I've been working with Java and noticed that constructors don't have a return type, unlike regular methods. I understand that constructors are used for initializing objects, but I'm curious about the specific reasons behind this design choice. Can someone provide insights into why Java constructors don't have a return type? What is the rationale behind not allowing constructors to specify a return type, and how does this design contribute to the language's principles and consistency?

Comment: What return type do you expect from a constructor if it had one?

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values

Comment: This question was likely down-voted for not showing the results of your own prior research on the subject. I'm not one of the down-voters and am not saying that you didn't do any research, just that you've not shown it, such was what the results of your own search of this site on similar questions brought you. In moving forward, please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your questions and their answers will be better making your future experiences here better.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/jls19.pdf) (p. 308), constructors are not methods, and they are not called in the same way as methods. If a constructor were to have a return type, there's no logical place for that return value to be accessed.

Calling `new MyObject()` returns a `MyObject` instance, if the constructor for the `MyObject` class returned an `int`, there's no place for it to go. You wouldn't want it to be `int x = new MyObject()`, or you wouldn't be able to access the object you'd just created.